# ViewPager not updating RecylcerView inside of each tab when switching

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, static-classes

I have a ViewPager that I set up in a simple example app. I have a single static fragment implemented as an inner-class with a RecylerView in it. I'd like to change the LayoutManager of the RecyclerView based on which tab I'm in. My implementation is show below. This is not working for me. When I load this ViewPager is starts in the 1st position but has a staggered layout (which should be for the 3rd position). When I swipe over to the 2nd position it is still the staggered layout, nothing changed as the getItem() method of my PagerAdapter was never called. When I switch over to the 3rd position is does call getItem() and the RecylerView is reloaded, however it still has the staggered layout (this is where it actually should have the staggered layout).

After reading up a bit on ViewPagers I'm realizing that the PagerAdapter will reuse the fragment if it determines that it can. I think that is what is happening here. Is there any way to keep this from happening? Can I get my LayoutManager to switch for each tab while just using one Fragment? Essentially I want it to instantiate a new Fragment for each tab.

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext){
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, TabbedActivity.class);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabbed, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class RecyclerFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_LAYOUT_TYPE = "layout-type";

        private int layoutType = 0;

        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        public ArrayList<AndroidVersion> data;
        public DataAdapter adapter;

        public static final int FRAGMENT_LINEAR = 0;
        public static final int FRAGMENT_GRID = 1;
        public static final int FRAGMENT_STAG_GRID = 2;

        public static RecyclerFragment newInstance(int layoutType) {
            Timber.d("newInstance() called with int: " + layoutType);
            RecyclerFragment fragment = new RecyclerFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_LAYOUT_TYPE, layoutType);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if(getArguments() != null){
                layoutType = getArguments().getInt(ARG_LAYOUT_TYPE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_linear, container, false);

            Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent mainActivityIntent = MainActivity.newIntent(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
                }
            });

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_recyler_view_pager);
            //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            // Check to see what the layout type should be and create the necessary LayoutManager
            switch(layoutType){
                case FRAGMENT_LINEAR:
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                case FRAGMENT_GRID:
                    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
                case FRAGMENT_STAG_GRID:
                    StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
            }

            loadJSON();

            return rootView;
        }

        private void loadJSON() {
            Retrofit retrofit = MainActivity.getRestAdapter();
            RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
            Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
                    JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                    data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getAndroid()));
                    adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            Timber.d("getItem called, position: " + position);
            return RecyclerFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Linear";
                case 1:
                    return "Grid";
                case 2:
                    return "Staggered";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put updates on `ViewPager#addOnPageChangeListener`

Comment: I can't directly update the Fragment from the ViewPager activity though, since it is a static fragment. I tried calling `sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(position)` from inside the addOnPageChangeListener() call, but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

inside the RecyclerFragment class define a static variable :

private static RecyclerFragment instance = null;

and change newInstance method like below :

```
public static RecyclerFragment newInstance(int layoutType) {
            Timber.d("newInstance() called with int: " + layoutType);
            instance =new RecyclerFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_LAYOUT_TYPE, layoutType);
            instance.setArguments(args);
            return instance;
        }
```